# Log Method Calls in Java System Classes

Tags: java, aop, aspectj, powermock, jmockit

I'm looking for a way to log calls to all methods in `java.nio.ByteBuffer`.

I just want to know which methods are being called.

This was possible with JMockit, but as of version 1.47 some infinitely wise individual decided to remove support of private methods & version 1.46 doesn't work too well with JDK 9 and later.

Can anyone suggest a tool?  It doesn't necessarily need to be a Unit-Test framework, but it should work in Eclipse.

I need at least support for JDK 11 (preferably JDK 13)

Just for the record, here's the code that works with JMockit 1.46 & JDK 1.8:

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.slf4j.*;
import mockit.*;

public class TestFakeByteBufferAdvice {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestFakeByteBufferAdvice.class);

    public static final class FakeByteBuffer extends MockUp<ByteBuffer> {
        @Mock
        public Object $advice(Invocation invocation) {
            LOG.info("$advice.....: {} {}", invocation.getInvokedMember(), invocation);

            return invocation.proceed();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void getFakeByteBuffer() {

        final ByteBuffer real  = ByteBuffer.wrap("abc".getBytes());
        LOG.info("Real........: {} {}", real, real.array());

        LOG.info("MockUp......: {}",    new FakeByteBuffer());

        final ByteBuffer fake  = ByteBuffer.wrap("def".getBytes());
        LOG.info("Fake........: {} {}", fake, fake.array());
    }
}
```

Comment: Are we talking about intercepting `ByteBuffer` methods called by your own code or do you also need to know calls made by JRE classes internally? As for an AOP-based answer, it makes a difference, thus my question.

Comment: I'm looking to trace JRE classes calling ByteBuffer (in particular the Publisher stuff in the new Java 9 Http Client, which was further enhanced in Java 13)

Comment: Then you cannot use AspectJ load-time weaving because `java` and `javax` classes are not exposed to the weaver. The only way to do it would be to use binary weaving, compiling aspects directly into the JRE and creating your own woven JRE version. I have done that before with older Java versions, it worked nicely. Maybe that is over-engineering and definitely not a good idea for production use, but in order to learn about the JRE it might be a viable approach. You could learn just as much by using a debugger, though.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, I managed to hack my way to a solution.

Firstly, JMockit doesn't work very well with JDK13, so I backported the JDK13 Http Client to JDK8. Its an evil hack, but sufficient for my test-case.

Then I used a slightly older Version (1.46) of JMockit because some comedian decided that no one should be allowed to Fake classes with private methods.

Then I stored the objects I wanted to trace in a List, which makes it possible to exclude unwanted Objects from Logging via an identity (==) comparison.

Still JMockit may crash on some methods (in the example below, I've commented them out), so it's an idea to suppress the logging after the Exception.
I've reported this to the JMockit people:
https://github.com/jmockit/jmockit1/issues/667

Similarly, it makes sense to suppress the logging while constructing the test-case to keep the Output quantities down. I used an AtomicBoolean for that.

Still the trace didn't solve it completely, but throwing in a Stacktrace led me to the solution: the following Call-chain was reading my ByteBuffers:
sun.nio.ch.write(ByteBuffer[] srcs, int offset, int length)
sun.nio.ch.write(FileDescriptor fd, ByteBuffer src, long position, NativeDispatcher nd)
java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.put(ByteBuffer src)

The DirectByteBuffer was using some clever tricks to read out my ByteBuffer.

The solution only works with my Http Client hack, but here it is anyway, just for the record. Maybe some of it will help others debugging some other classes:

```
package http.jmockit;

import java.net.*;
import java.net.http.*;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest.BodyPublisher;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import org.slf4j.*;
import mockit.*;

public class TestHttpIdentity {

    private static final Logger        LOG         = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestHttpIdentity.class);
    private static final AtomicBoolean LOG_ENABLED = new AtomicBoolean();
    private static final List<Object>  TRACKED     = new ArrayList<>();

    public static final class FakeByteBuffer extends MockUp<ByteBuffer> {
        @Mock
        public Object $advice(final Invocation invocation) {

            if (TRACKED.stream().noneMatch(tracked -> tracked == invocation.getInvokedInstance())) {
                return invocation.proceed();
            }

            if (LOG_ENABLED.get()) {
                LOG    .info("$advice.invokedInstance.: {}", invocation.getInvokedInstance(), "" /* (makes signature unique)*/);
                LOG    .info("$advice.invokedMember...: {}", invocation.getInvokedMember(),   "" /* (makes signature unique)*/);
//              Thread.dumpStack(); // Use Stack Trace as last measure if needs be
            }

            Object     result = "Not available due to Exception in invocation.proceed()";
            try {
                /**/   result = invocation.proceed();
                return result;
            }
            catch (final Throwable e) {

                for (final Object arg : invocation.getInvokedArguments()) {
                    LOG.info("$advice.arg.............: {} class={}", arg,   arg == null ? "?" : arg.getClass());
                }
                LOG    .info("$advice.Result..........: {}", result);

                LOG_ENABLED.set(false);  // Disable Logging when JMockit fails

                try {Thread.sleep(100);} catch (final InterruptedException shortDelayToSyncLoggingOutput) {}

                e.printStackTrace();
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {

        LOG.info("MockUp..................: {}", new FakeByteBuffer());

        final ByteBuffer[] byteBuffers  = TestBytes.asWrappedByteBuffers();

        for (final ByteBuffer byteBuffer : byteBuffers) {
            LOG.info("byteBuffer..............: {}", byteBuffer);

            final int limit    = byteBuffer.limit();
            final int position = byteBuffer.position();

            TRACKED.add(byteBuffer);  // Track Objects via their Identity (==)

            LOG.info("Test Bytes..............: {}", byteBuffers, "");
            LOG.info("byteBuffer0.array().....: {}", byteBuffer.array());
            LOG.info("byteBuffer0.capacity()..: {}", byteBuffer.capacity());
            LOG.info("byteBuffer0.get().......: {}", byteBuffer.get());
//          LOG.info("byteBuffer0.get(byte[]).: {}", byteBuffers0.get(new byte[5]));  // ClassCastException
            LOG.info("byteBuffer0.get(byte[]->) {}", byteBuffer.get(new byte[5], 0, 5));
            LOG.info("byteBuffer0.get(0)......: {}", byteBuffer.get(0));
            LOG.info("byteBuffer0.hasArray()..: {}", byteBuffer.hasArray());
            LOG.info("byteBuffer0.hasRemaining: {}", byteBuffer.hasRemaining());
            LOG.info("byteBuffer0.isDirect()..: {}", byteBuffer.isDirect());
            LOG.info("byteBuffer0.isReadOnly(): {}", byteBuffer.isReadOnly());
            LOG.info("byteBuffer0.limit().....: {}", limit);
            LOG.info("byteBuffer0.limit(0)....: {}", byteBuffer.limit(limit));
            LOG.info("byteBuffer0.mark(0).....: {}", byteBuffer.mark());
            LOG.info("byteBuffer0.order().....: {}", byteBuffer.order());
            LOG.info("byteBuffer0.position()..: {}", position);
            LOG.info("byteBuffer0.position(99): {}", byteBuffer.position(99));
            LOG.info("byteBuffer0.remaining().: {}", byteBuffer.remaining());
//          LOG.info("byteBuffer0.reset().....: {}", byteBuffers0.reset());      // -> InvalidMarkException
            LOG.info("byteBuffer0.rewind()....: {}", byteBuffer.rewind());
            LOG.info("byteBuffer0.slice().....: {}", byteBuffer.slice());

            byteBuffer.rewind();
            byteBuffer.position(position);
            byteBuffer.limit   (limit);

            LOG.info("byteBuffer..............: {}", byteBuffer);
        }
        final BodyPublisher pub = new ByteArrayBodyPublisherIterator(byteBuffers);

        LOG_ENABLED.set(false);  // Enable Logging now we've got things set up.

        final HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(new URI("http://localhost:631"))
                .headers("Content-Type", "application/ipp")
                .POST(pub)
                .build();

        HttpResponse<byte[]> response = HttpClient
                .newBuilder()
                .build()
                .send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofByteArray());

        LOG.info("Result......: {} {}", response, response.body());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is for the purpose of learning or analysis, why don't you just use a debugger? I am going to show you an example in IntelliJ IDEA:

**Given** this code somewhere in your `main` method or test:

```java
final ByteBuffer real  = ByteBuffer.wrap("abc".getBytes());
LOG.info("Real........: {} {}", real, real.array());
```

**When** defining a method breakpoint in the debugger like this:

[image: Create Java method breakpoint]

[image: Specify class and method name pattern]

**And** defining its properties like this (breakpoint does not suspend running program but logs method entry, other filter criteria and log information is also possible):

[image: Specify breakpoint properties]

**Then** you will get a console log like this (shortened because it is quite long):

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:54734', transport: 'socket'
Method 'java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate()' entered at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:333)
Method 'java.nio.ByteBuffer.<init>()' entered at java.nio.ByteBuffer.<init>(ByteBuffer.java:281)
Method 'java.nio.ByteBuffer.hasArray()' entered at java.nio.ByteBuffer.hasArray(ByteBuffer.java:970)
Method 'java.nio.ByteBuffer.array()' entered at java.nio.ByteBuffer.array(ByteBuffer.java:993)
Method 'java.nio.ByteBuffer.arrayOffset()' entered at java.nio.ByteBuffer.arrayOffset(ByteBuffer.java:1021)
(...)
Method 'java.nio.ByteBuffer.wrap()' entered at java.nio.ByteBuffer.wrap(ByteBuffer.java:396)
Method 'java.nio.ByteBuffer.wrap()' entered at java.nio.ByteBuffer.wrap(ByteBuffer.java:373)
Method 'java.nio.ByteBuffer.<init>()' entered at java.nio.ByteBuffer.<init>(ByteBuffer.java:281)
Method 'java.nio.ByteBuffer.array()' entered at java.nio.ByteBuffer.array(ByteBuffer.java:993)
Method 'java.nio.ByteBuffer.toString()' entered at java.nio.ByteBuffer.toString(ByteBuffer.java:1085)
08:23:16.943 [main] INFO  d.s.s.q.TestFakeByteBufferAdvice - Real........: java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=3 cap=3] [97, 98, 99]
Method 'java.nio.ByteBuffer.hasArray()' entered at java.nio.ByteBuffer.hasArray(ByteBuffer.java:970)
Method 'java.nio.ByteBuffer.array()' entered at java.nio.ByteBuffer.array(ByteBuffer.java:993)
(...)
Method 'java.nio.ByteBuffer.arrayOffset()' entered at java.nio.ByteBuffer.arrayOffset(ByteBuffer.java:1021)
Method 'java.nio.ByteBuffer.array()' entered at java.nio.ByteBuffer.array(ByteBuffer.java:993)
Method 'java.nio.ByteBuffer.arrayOffset()' entered at java.nio.ByteBuffer.arrayOffset(ByteBuffer.java:1021)
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:54734', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Play around with the breakpoint options and find a setting which helps you the most. You could for example filter out certain methods of no interest or specify other conditions, evaluate expressions and log them or whatever you dream up.

---

**Update 2020-05-17:** It took a few weeks for JetBrains to react, but they agreed to improve the documentation and also to fix one bug:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DOC-9130
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-240671

Comment: Hi Alexander, vielen dank das du Zeit genommen hast. I'll continue in english for the community.  I'm playing around with an Open-Source Java Client for Cups (as the ones available right now are pretty limited) & wanted to know how best to supply my ByteBuffers to the new Http Client, so I wanted to know how they're being used. Ideally I'd like to know where the call is coming from too. The IntelliJ IDEA log looks quite good. Do you happen to know if the logging is available in the Community Edition? 
Regards from the Odenwald, Dave.

Comment: Actually I don't know exactly because I use Ultimate Edition, but I would expect it to work in Community as well. Just give it a try. Here is the corresponding [manual chapter](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-breakpoints.html).

Comment: I might just give that a go, after all I've tried just about everything else this week from Mockito over PowerMock to Spock & JMockit. But all these tools seem more or less broken since Java 9. No wonder the world is still using Java 8!

Comment: I've tried it out on the current Community Edition (v2019.3.4). It works. Sort of. It would be nice to find some way of only logging "my" ByteBuffer. I tried entering  `hashCode();` under `Evaluate and log:` with the intention of extracting "my" instances, but it causes the JVM to crash. The `Stack Trace` option is also quite handy, but its still practically impossible to find out who's doing what with my ByteBuffer.

Comment: Hm, yes, the documentation for debugger filters and conditions in not good, I even complained to JetBrains support about it. They asked for details what I was missing and I just sent them a long list. Let's see if they improve anything. Tracking method calls on a single instance is something I also didn't manage to do when I tried after your previous comment. I will tell you when I know more, this is an interesting use case. But I might be busy today.

Comment: In the mean time I've backported the JDK13 Http Client to JDK8 and am trying to debug it with JMockit. Trouble is: JMockit gets its methods muddled & is sometimes throwing ClassCastExceptions (https://github.com/jmockit/jmockit1/issues/667), so I'm running out of options, but one nice thing is I can use the identity (==) to single out "my" ByteBuffers.

Comment: Please note my answer update about the reaction of JetBrains concerning documentation and a debugger bug.